# Ruby on rails problem with mysql2 when creating linux service

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have installed ruby2.7. When i try to run my code from command line using. But when i create a service by creating a file /lib/systemd/system/abc.service. when i start this service using command systemctl start abc it gives me an error.

Oct 19 05:21:31 localhost fever-log: /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2 (LoadError)

I am stuck with this error why its giving error when i try to run the same code from service.

Comment: How did you install the `mysql2` gem?

Comment: gem install mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config

Comment: Did you install the gem as the same user that runes the service?

Comment: Yes, it was installed with root account.